# Python: Parentheses inside square brackets (Lists)

Tags: python

What's the difference of a list enclosed by parentheses vs. one without

```
list_a = ['hello','world']

list_b = [('hello'),('world')]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `list_b` elements don't have a trailing comma `,` inside the parentheses? Like `('hello',)` etc .

Comment: `list_b` is a list of `tuples`.

Comment: One is a list of strings, the other is **supposed** to be a list of tuples

Comment: @MayankPorwal Almost... the comma is missing. It's still a list of strings

Comment: @DeepSpace Ya. I notice your `supposed` in bold. My bad.

Comment: so a list of dict would be list_c = [{'key1':value1},{'key2':value2}]?

Comment: @user12625679 Correct.